# Recorrer la parte numerica de una lista compuesta por numeros y str python

Tags: python

```
Lista_direcciones=["10-D","-65-I","-30-I","900-D","65-I","15-D","89-I","35-I","9-D","650-I","-900-D","5-I","10-D","-65-I","-30-I","900-D","65-I","9-I","35-D","5-D","10-I","-65-D","-30-D"]
```

Deseo eliminar la letra `D` y `I` y que me quede solo el entero, esto se puede? y como lo podría hacer intente hacer un recorrido con un `for`

```py
for i in range(0, tamaño):
    print(Lista_direcciones[i])  
    Lista_direcciones[].pop(1:-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) podemos capturar directamente los valores numéricos y convertirlos a enteros.

```
import re

lista_enteros = [int(re.search(r"(-\d+|\d+)", e)[0]) for e in lista_direcciones]

print(lista_enteros)

[10, -65, -30, 900, 65, 15, 89, 35, 9, 650, -900, 5, 10, -65, -30, 900, 65, 9, 35, 
 5, 10, -65, -30]
```

---

El patrón `(-\d+|\d+)` "captura" dígito ya sean que representen números postivos o negativos y lo aplicamos mediante `re.search()` sobre cada elemento de la lista usando una comprensión de listas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de 2 formas, utilizando una expresión regular o verificando si `-` esta en la cadena.

**Comprobando la cadena**

Aquí buscaremos el caracter `-` y obtendremos su posición con `.index()`, el principal problema son los números negativos, por tal razón tomaremos la cadena desde su segundo caracter, esto usando un *slice*

```py
new_list = [] #aqui se alacenara los numeros extraidos
for dir in Lista_direcciones: #recorremos
    if "-" in dir: #verificamos si se encuentra
        #cogemos desde el segundo y le sumamos 1 al indice que nos devuelve
        sep = dir[1:].index("-")+1 
        num = dir[:sep] #cogemos solo el numero
        new_list.append(num) #agregamos a la lista

print(new_list )
```

**resultado**

```
['10', '-65', '-30', '900', '65', '15', '89', '35', '9', '650', '-900', '5', '10', '-65', '-30', '900', '65', '9', '35', '5', '10', '-65', '-30']
```

Para coger el numero utilizamos nuevamente la notación de *slice*, donde cogeremos la cadena desde la posición inicial hasta el numero que nos devuelva el índice (variable `sep`)

**Con expresión regular**

Al hacerlo con una expresion regular se nos facilita bastante el trabajo, para ello utilizaremos el modulo `re`. De la misma forma lo haremos con un ciclo `for` pero al no necesitar tanto código podemos usar una comprensión de lista.

```py
import re
#coincide con cualquier cadena que termine con un guion seguido de una letra
regex = re.compile(r"-\w$")

#iteramos en la lista y aplicamos el split de la expresion regular 
#y obtenemos el primer elemento
new_list = [regex.split(dir)[0] for dir in Lista_direcciones]
print(new_list)
```

Para separar el string usamos el metodo `split()` de nuestra expresión regular, la cual nos devuelve, en este caso, una lista con 2 elementos, el primero tiene el numero y el segundo una cadena vacia (que es la separación de `-\w`)

**resultado**

```
['10', '-65', '-30', '900', '65', '15', '89', '35', '9', '650', '-900', '5', '10', '-65', '-30', '900', '65', '9', '35', '5', '10', '-65', '-30']
```

Answer (score 0):

Nada rebuscado:

```
lista = [int(x[:-2]) for x in lista_direcciones]
```

Es una comprensión de listas que toma cada elemento, elimina los dos últimos caracteres y convierte a entero el resulatdo.

**Demo**

```
lista_direcciones=["10-D","-65-I","-30-I","900-D","65-I","15-D","89-I","35-I","9-D","650-I","-900-D","5-I","10-D","-65-I","-30-I","900-D","65-I","9-I","35-D","5-D","10-I","-65-D","-30-D"]
lista = [int(x[:-2]) for x in lista_direcciones]
print(lista)
```

produce

```
[10, -65, -30, 900, 65, 15, 89, 35, 9, 650, -900, 5, 10, -65, -30, 900, 65, 9, 35, 5, 10, -65, -30]

Process finished with exit code 0
```